# Do I need to always define move and copy for left/right value in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a class with some instance variable `x`, and I would like to do the following setter method for this instance variable: when the argument is a left value, the value is copied to `x`, while if the argument is a right value, the value is moved to `x`. So here is what I did:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    void setX(const Something& y) {x = y;}
    void setX(Something&& y) {x = y;}

private:
    Something x;
}
```

The question is: do I always do duplicate my functions like this? If I have 3 arguments, and I would like to move whenever possible, and copy if the original argument is a left value, I will have to consider all kinds of combinations of left/right values. How should I avoid the duplicate in here?

Comment: Why does `setX` _require_ a reference to an already existing value?

Comment: Most of the time you will be fine with taking your arguments *by value*, as opposed to by `const&` or `&&` and simply `std::move` the copies to your argumets. If your cycles are that important **and** you are certain that you need to optimise for speed, you can use *forwarding references* and make `setX` a `template` that accepts a *forwarding reference* and then `std::forward` it to `x`.

Comment: FYI, in `void setX(Something&& y)`, `y` itself is an lvalue not an rvalue, so you need `x = std::move(y);` to invoke a proper move assignment.